# Xdebug as a reference counting works

Tags: php, xdebug

The documentation has a few fragments illustrate how this works, but one thing is not clear, I illustrate it below:

```
/// Example 1
$a = 10;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 2
$a = 10;
$b = 10;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 3
$a = 10;
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 4
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10

/// Example 5
$a = 10;
$b = $a;
$c = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 6
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$c = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10

/// Example 7
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
$c = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a','b','c');
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
```

For all of the examples most illogical for me turned out to be `Example 6`, I really do not understand why we have to debug when we do not get all lines of the following entry

```
/// Output:
/// a:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// b:(refcount=3, is_ref=1),int 10
/// c:(refcount=3, is_ref=0),int 10
```

Explain what is the matter?

Comment: I really don't understand your question, can you clarify your doubt?

Comment: Look at `Example 3` and `Example 4` in both example summed refcount, but why in the `Example 6` is not summed as in the third and fourth example

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in terms of pointers from the C language, if you are familiar with it. Variables in PHP are pointers to ZVALs, so when you "copy" a variable in PHP, PHP does **not** actually duplicate its value, but increments the refcount and duplicates the pointer. But still if you alter the original value the other values do not change, because PHP does something called **copy-on-write** (unless refcount=1,

```
$a = 10;
$b = $a;  // $b is a soft copy of $a, refcount++
$a = 11;  // $a changes, a new zval is created
```

While:

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a; // $b is still a copy of a, but this time a reference
$a = 11;  // $a and $b change
```

So what happens in your "Example 6"? Well, PHP knows that refcount > 1, but you cannot "soft-copy" $a's zval into $c, because otherwise when you change $a or $b it would also change $c's value, so $c becomes a NEW zval, with refcount=1.

```
$a = 10;    // new zval created (refcount=1)
$b = &$a;   // $b is a copy of $a but is_ref=1 (and refcount=2)
$c = $a;    // $c is a NEW zval, refcount=1
```

I'm afraid I didn't explain myself well :( I can try again if you still have doubts.

Comment: I did not understand much of your explanation, I'm sorry
But I did not understand why create a new zval container? Due to the fact that the variable $a and $b variable are hard links?

Comment: Yes, sorry, tomorrow I'll try again I realize it wasn't clear at all. The problem is exactly that $a and $b are hard links.. this fact forces you to make a deep copy when you do $c = $b, because if you just incremented the refcount then you would have to go through all the hard-copies and change them all when you alter $c or $a/$b